Naming of polycyclic "sulflower"-like hydrocarbon
I was playing with ChemSpider for cool structures, and I built the next figure, a polycyclic hydrocarbon containing ten fused cyclopentane rings. How could I name this thing? Could it exist/be made?


The version with sulphur at the apex of the 5 membered ring is 'sulflower' or octathia[8]circulene which assumes the molecule is flat i.e. has some double bonds and so has D8h symmetry. I guess you loose the 'thia' in your compound.   see https://molecule-viewer.com/ for the structure

Just came here to bring up the "sulflower", for I was personally acquainted with some of the guys who made it. Then again, it had an 8-membered central ring, while this has 10. Also, it was $\pi$-conjugated all over, while this one is not. Still, the conclusion is as follows. Would this thing exist? Sure, why not. Can it be made? Go on, try it.

Unfortunately, drawing a pretty 2D projection of an inherently 3D molecule is generally not going to end well. I don't doubt it can be made if you burn enough person-dollar-years, but its crystal structure will just look like a garbled tangle of atoms.

SciFinder suggests the names triacontahydro-4,14,3-methyno-2,5-[1]propen[1]yl[3]ylidenebiscyclopenta[5,6]pentaleno[1,2-a:2′,1′-f]pentalene (ACI) and
[10,5,1]circulene, adds CAS 72863-55-9 and cites https://doi.org/10.1002/cphc.202400342.

I would go with undecacyclotriacontane with repeating numbers in brackets.

@NicolauSakerNeto Oh, I think it would be more interesting than that. Circulene is saddle-shaped, but this got even bigger inner ring, so I think the geometry is more complex, maybe two bowls with a common side.

The geometry of this thing would depend heavily on the (R,S)-configuration of all the atoms in the inner ring.

@IvanNeretin Yeah, but if any rings were "trans-fused" it would add even more strain.

Thought "sunflower" was intended until I looked up "sulflower". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulflower Perhaps worth inserting a link to explain what sulflower is?

The following compound, $\ce{C30H10}$ where 10 pentagonal rings surround a central decagon with 15 double bonds, is known as [10,5]-coronene (Ref.1 & 2):

Bochvar et al. (Ref. 3) initially introduced this hypothetical
structure, giving the name, coronene-10,5, and considered its geometrical and $\pi$-electron properties, some fifty years ago. In Ref. 3, it is stated that:

The regular coronenes-n,m satisfy the equation $m=4n/(n-2)$, where n is the number of vertices of the framed polygon and m that of the framing polygon. It is easy to verify that only four regular coronenes are possible, namely,coronenes−3,12, −4,8, −6,6, and −10,5.

Your compound, $\ce{C30H40}$, is the fully saturated version of [10,5]-coronene with extra 30 hydrogens. Hence, it should be named triacontahydro-[10,5]-coronene.
References:

Guglielmo Monaco, Rosario G. Viglione, Riccardo Zanasi, and Patrick W. Fowler, “Designing Ring-Current Patterns: [10,5]-Coronene, a Circulene with Inverted Rim and Hub Currents,” J. Phys. Chem. A 2006, 110(23), 7447–7452 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0600559).
T. K. Dickens and  R. B. Mallion, “$\pi$-Electron ring-currents and bond-currents in [10,5]-Coronene and related structures conforming to the ‘Annulene-Within-an-Annulene’ model,” Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys. 2013, 15(21), 8245-8253 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/C3CP00053B).
D. A. Bochvar, E. G. Gal'pern, and N. P. Gambaryan, “Calculation of the molecule of coronene-10,5 $(\ce{C30H10})$,” Russ. Chem. Bull. 1970,19, 377–379 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00853389) (Translated from Izvestiya Akademii Nauk SSSR, Seriya Khimicheskaya 1970, No. 2, pp. 435–437).

